# Check if Timetstamp is older than 1 hour not working?

Tags: php

Not sure why but this if statement is not working. What am i doing wrong here?

```
$timestamp = $order->datetime;
if ($timestamp >= strtotime("-1 hour")) {
    echo "PULL FROM DB!";
} else {
    echo "PULL FROM API";
}
```

Thanks

Comment: what's the error you are getting ?

Comment: It just says "PULL FROM API" even if the timestamp is later or earlier

Comment: Is the value of `$timestamp` what you expect it to be? Maybe that might help work out what is going on.

Comment: `echo $order->datetime;` show the result of this. Problem is here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to compare a date string to a timestamp. What you are actually comparing in your if statement is like the following:

```
if("2015-10-16 08:21:11" >= 1444987642){
 echo "PULL FROM DB!";
} else {
 echo "PULL FROM API";
}
```

This is not what you want. You need to convert your date string into a timestamp before you compare it. Try this instead:

```
$dateString = $order->datetime;
$timestamp = strtotime($dateString);

if ($timestamp >= strtotime("-1 hour")) {
    echo "PULL FROM DB!";
} else {
    echo "PULL FROM API";
}
```

The key part is that you convert the date string to a timestamp:

`$timestamp = strtotime($dateString);`

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```
$timestamp = strtotime("now");
if ($timestamp >= strtotime("-1 hour")) {
    echo "PULL FROM DB!";
} else {
    echo "PULL FROM API";
}
```

RESULT: PULL FROM DB!
and

```
$timestamp = strtotime("now");
if ($timestamp >= strtotime("1 hour")) {
    echo "PULL FROM DB!";
} else {
    echo "PULL FROM API";
}
```

RESULT: PULL FROM API

Please check the value you are passing in

```
$timestamp = $order->datetime;
```

Comment: @Elevant - Like Sumit says, you need to check the value of $timestamp because it's probably not what you think it is.

Try: `echo $timestamp;` and see what comes out.

Comment: echo displays 2015-10-16 08:21:11 which is what is in the Table? Maybe there is something wrong with my IF?

Comment: @Elevant : you are not having timestamp. You have do startotime(2015-10-16 08:21:11) to get timestamp